# Get the set of objects from Many To One relationship two levels deep

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have 3 models and I'd like to get the set of all related object from the 3rd model given the 1st model.

For example:

```
Clas Dealer(models.Model):
..

class Make(models.Model):
dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealer)
..

Class Modell(models.Model):
Make = models.ForeignKey(Make)
..
```

How would I go about getting all of the related `Modell` objects given the `Dealer?` The Dealer object is getting passed in the form of  `kwargs['instance']`

**Edit**
I can't use `.objects.filter(..)`

**Edit 2**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db import models


class CarConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'cars'
    verbose_name = 'cars'


    def ready(self):
        from cars.models import Car, Make, Modell
        models.signals.post_save.connect(CarConfig.reindex_related_carmodels, sender=Dealer, weak=False,
                                             dispatch_uid="reindex_related_carmodels")

        @staticmethod
        def reindex_related_carmodels(sender, **kwargs):
            from cars.search_indexes import ModelIndex
            models = Modell.objects.all()
            ...
```

The error I'm getting is: `global name 'Modell' is not defined`

**Edit 3**
If I try to import any of the models outside of ready, I get:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
web_1  |     raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
web_1  | django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

**Edit 4**
The solution is to do the model imports inside the @staticmethod :)

Comment: *Why* do you think you can't use filter? That is the  way to get things from the database. What do you intend to use instead?

Comment: I'm updating signals in a python file in apps.py. `from django.apps import AppConfig`. Therefore I'm pretty sure I can't use .filter. If I can, I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Er, what does that have to do with anything? Why does that mean you can't use filter?

Comment: Because you dont have access to the Djano Manager at that level

Comment: Yes you do. Please show the actual code where you are doing this, and the error you get when you try.

Comment: Hm ok. I just added it

Comment: It's not defined because you imported it inside `ready`, so it's only defined there.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a query like

```
Model.objects.filter(Make__dealer=kwargs['instance'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I can't use objects.filter, that is the issue. I'll add an edit

Comment: After resolving my import issue the above works. as expected.